# Crystal Reports switch stored procedure and add parameter with value

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I have single report that I want to use in two ways.
By default report is generating multiple pages, because stored procedure that is set as source is returning multiple elements.
I would like to programmatically replace stored procedure and add tarameter value to it.

First (default) procedure don't have any parameters, but second have one.

I'm loading my report like this:

```
var crReportDocument = new ReportDocument();
crReportDocument.Load(source);
if (generateForSingle)
{
    var crConnectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo
    {
        ServerName = "DEV",
        DatabaseName = reportServerName,
        IntegratedSecurity = true
    };

    var crTableLogonInfo = new TableLogOnInfo
    {
        ConnectionInfo = crConnectionInfo,
    };

    foreach (Table table in crReportDocument.Database.Tables)
    {
        table.ApplyLogOnInfo(crTableLogonInfo);
        table.Location = "STORED_PROCEDURE_SINGLE_RECORD;1";
    }
    crReportDocument.Refresh();
    crReportDocument.SetParameterValue("@RecordId",2532);

    //crReportDocument.Refresh();
    //ParameterFields parameterFields = new ParameterFields();
    //ParameterField parameterField = null;
    //ParameterDiscreteValue parameterValue = null;

    //parameterField = new ParameterField();
    //parameterValue = new ParameterDiscreteValue();
    //parameterField.Name = "@RecordId";
    //parameterValue.Value = "2532";
    //parameterField.CurrentValues.Add(parameterValue);
    //parameterFields.Add(parameterField);

    //crReportDocument.SetParameterValue("@RecordId", parameterValue);
    }
```

But every time I try to switch source procedure and set parameter value I get error saying that index is invalid `DISP_E_BADINDEX`

I started wondering if this is possible.

I need to have single report and be able to run in in two ways:

1. default - without switching source stored procedure - it generates multiple pages
2. with replaced source stored procedure and parameter value set to specific record_id.

is this possible?

Comment: You cannot do this, or at least it is not safe. What is the reason to change stored procedure name ?

Comment: @Lan - I have already working report that I can't edit, it is using stored procedure without parameters and generates multiple pages, I want to replace source procedury with one that has parameter so I'll be able to pass record_id to generate pages for single record.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the datasource of the report in Crystal designer. However this is will be one time operation and you do not need to change the code ( except to set the report's parameters)
Click on menu Database -> Set DataSourse Location. In the dialog box select your stored procedure (In "Cuurent Data Source" tree at tyhe top). In "Repace with" tree at the bottom select your connection (or create a new one ) find and select the new stored procedure  and click button "Update"  (on right). You need to verify the report after that.